# SQL Server : counting the number of rows in the second result-set

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure `SPROC1` which has reference to another stored procedure `SPROC2` to get the count of records. The problem is, `SPROC2` returns two result sets.

I need to get the count of second result-set alone inside `SPROC1`.

I tried with below query but it returns 0

```
EXEC SPROC2 @Id
SELECT @@rowcount
```

Is there any other possibility to achieve the same using `@@rowcount` or any other option?

Comment: Why not get the count inside the SP?

Comment: Also, why have you tagged 3 different version of SQL Server? Tag only the version you are actually using please.

Comment: @Larnu -  I want the count of First SP's second resultset in my second SP. Since both SPs are used for different purpose.

Comment: Then why not obtain and pass it back from the first? If it's important you know how many rows were affected by an SP, the logic should be in the SP.

Comment: @Larnu - I cannot modify the FirstSP only I can read the SP resultset.

Comment: Well, `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the rows in the second dataset works... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=329696f1a8f89db2db3dcf1df2a9bb6d), so I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: @Larnu - After setting NOCOUNT to OFF it works.

Answer (score 1):

I set  the clause NOCOUNT to OFF in the stored procedure, it worked :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SPROC2 
@Id int 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE SYSTEM_ID < @Id

SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE SYSTEM_ID < @Id

END
GO
```

then  run

```
EXEC SPROC2 @Id   -- with @Id set to a meaning value
SELECT  @@rowcount
```

it returned the TABLE2 count.

Comment: @ It is not working in my case. I set not count off but still returns 0.

Comment: @Ask_SO  it's strange.  Here a method to check if the settings is working: 

select @@OPTIONS&512 

if the result is 0 then "Set nocount off" is applied. If the result is 512 the "Set nocount on" is applied.